# An admin (GUI or shell tool) for managing all kinds of databases

Tags: management

I needed an interface/admin (web or desktop) from which I could manage all the databases in my system. Currently I use separate admins for each (phpmyadmin for mysql, pgadmin/phppgadmin for postgres, sqlite manager in firefox for sqlite etc). Whenever I have to work with all the databases, the only option I am left with is shell access to all the databases.

I wanted to know if there is an admin which can manage all kinds of databases in a single interface, possibly similar to the one used by jennifer widom in her [coursera lectures](https://class.coursera.org/db/lecture/index)?

Comment: With "admin" you mean some kind of GUI tool?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. actually didn't know what exact term to use. Feel free to edit the question if you think is necessary

Comment: I'm happily using http://www.sql-workbench.net (cross-platform and cross-operating system). It doesn't have a specialized "DBA GUI" for specific DBMS features though - you (mostly) need to find your way around using pure SQL.

Comment: hm.. I fine even with pure SQL. Will check it out. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: There's Embarcadero's [DB Artisan](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/dbartisan) which works with heterogeneous environments, with distinct db servers. But it's a paid tool and you didn't specify what your options are.

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late, but the product [Data Utensil](http://maxotek.com/products/data_utensil) aims to be just that. As of now, it supports SQL Server, My SQL, Oracle & Firebird (embedded).

**Disclosure:** I work for Maxotek, who created Data Utensil.

Comment: You should explicitly identify your association with a product when answering a question with a link.  I realize you said "our product", however this is not the same as saying something like "disclosure: I work for XYZ company, who created the xyz product"

Comment: seems pretty good. Will give it a try sometime soon

Answer (score 1):

You can try Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/) which supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MS SQL, Oracle

An additional beauty with this is that its a single PHP file that is deployed to your server

Answer (score 0):

SquirrelSQL http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net supports a wide range of jdbc compliant DB's.